# The value '[object HTMLInputElement]' is not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am getting the following error when submitting the form:

```
The value '[object HTMLInputElement]' is not valid for MaritalStatus
```

this is the Model:

```
public class CompanionsModel
{
        public char Gender { get; set; }
        public int MaritalStatus { get; set; }
}
```

this is the view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="MaritalStatus" name="MaritalStatus" data-bind="value: MaritalStatus" value="@Model.MaritalStatus" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Gender, new {data_bind="value: StudentGender" })
```

this is the knockoutsjs code:

```
 function CompanionController() {
            var self = this;
            var GenderValue = $("[name=Gender]").val();
            var MaritalStatusValue = $("#MaritalStatus").val();

            self.StudentGender = ko.observable(GenderValue); 

            self.StudentMaritalStatus = ko.observable(MaritalStatusValue);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error was because the invalid Knockouts data-binding in the 'MaritalStatus' checkbox

the correct binding is ' **StudentMaritalStatus**' NOT 'MaritalStatus'

```
<input type="hidden" id="MaritalStatus" name="MaritalStatus" data-bind="value: StudentMaritalStatus" value="@Model.MaritalStatus" />
```